# how to print javascript value in input field value

Tags: javascript, html

I want to print the javascript code in input field value

I want to add id="#id" in input field value so that I can submit the from with user ip

for example
i want to print ABC using this code given below in input value=""

```
<input type="hidden" value="">
```

```
<script>
  $.getJSON("https://api.ipify.org?format=json", function(data) {
  // Setting text of element P with id gfg
$("#ip").html(data.ip);
  })
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Call `.val()`

This looks like jQuery. In that case use [.val(data.ip)](https://api.jquery.com/val/#val-value) to set a form field's value. Read the documentation for more information on handling forms.

You also do not have `id="ip"` in the HTML of your question - assuming you just left that out - otherwise check if the id attribute is set.

For demonstration I changed the input to a `type="text"` below, but a `type="hidden"` field works just as well.

```js
  // pretend we got a reply from the API:
  var data = { ip: '127.0.0.1' };
  
  // Setting text of element with id "ip"
  $("#ip").val(data.ip);
```

```css
form { border: 1px dashed #909; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
<!-- changed to type text so you see the result, but hidden works too -->
<input id="ip" name="ip" type="text" value="">
</form>
```